# In IE6 div not taking available height while taking in IE7 and FF?

Tags: css, xhtml

In IE6 div not taking available height while taking in IE7 and FF?

`height` not defined on `div`

In IE6 `div` taking height according to content inside `div` while in IE7 and FF `div` taking full available height

Comment: Care to post some code...or a question? We need a little more than just a question mark

Comment: A screenshot would help even more. One for broken and one for expected result

Comment: IE6 just plain doesn't support a lot of things.

Comment: [`status-norepro`](http://jsbin.com/abale3). Post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Answer (score 0):

Just based on what little you provided...

Try: `<div style="height:XXpx;">`

But it would be glorious if you posted code and a real question...

Comment: i don't want to give fixed height to div.